# Finding records created 10 days ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My initial thought was:

```
user.humans.where("created_at = ?", 10.days.ago)
```

Though, this seems to be looking for the record created 10 days ago at the exact time when the statement is called. I want to collect the records created on that day, regardless of their time.

Is anyone aware of a convenient way to do this? Let me know if I need to elaborate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You'll probably want to use a range here, as I assume this is a datetime column.

```
User.humans.where("? <= created_at AND created_at <= ?", 10.days.ago.beginning_of_day, 10.days.ago.end_of_day)
```

You'll also want to make sure you're setting the time zone of your Rails application so that you're explicit about which time period you consider to be the 10th day.

Comment: If you're using postgres, you can do `"created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?"`.

Answer (score 2):

Whichever DBMS you are using will have a method to convert a datetime to a date.  You should then compare this to a date in ruby.  For example, if your DBMS is MySQL you could say

```
user.humans.where("date(created_at) = ?", 10.days.ago.to_date)
```

If you're not using MySQL then you should be able to google converting a datetime to a date in your DBMS of choice.